# Wordpress hyperlink to editable Excel document

Tags: wordpress, excel, hyperlink

I have this personal WordPress site and would like to add hyperlinks that when clicked instantly open an excel file that i would be able to edit then save my changes.
I would also help if i could do this for other programs.

Thanks

Comment: Is the site public? Do you want other people to be able to open and edit those files? Where are those files stored? Locally on your computer, or on your server?

Comment: And you want anyone in the world to edit them? What if someone doesn't have Excel installed on their computer?